# How to check style arbitrary list of java files from command line?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I want to have an opportunity to pass the list of *.java files in commit/changeset to the pre-commit hook which will check those java files for code style.

I've tried to use [maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin) but it looks like it is not possible to pass to it an arbitrary list of files. Also, running `mvn site` builds reports which are not supposed to be used exclusively like a human-readable entity, so it is not trivial to use this report in python scripts (which mercurial hooks basically are).

So the question is: how to check-style an arbitrary list of *.java files in command-line (just like we are checking arbitrary list of python files with pep8, or javascript files with jshint/jslint)?

By style-checking I mean not only printing report to stdout but returning somehow the final result - whether files had or had not passed the guidelines.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @JimGarrison let's me try to edit this to make it clear. It is not about most common used pattern, not about finding a tool or library .

Comment: @JimGarrison have edited the question. I understand about what kind of off-topic questions you are talking about, but hope now the question looks like not of that kind. Questions like "best practices for copying files in grunt" are not off-topic.

Comment: @Thomas I've tried to use maven-checkstyle-plugin (it is actually mentioned in this question) and calling checkstyle from command line - http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html

Answer (score 16):

if I understand rightly, you want to check not all Java sources in the project, only some specific files?

```
# this checks all *.java sources
mvn checkstyle:checkstyle -Dcheckstyle.includes=**\/*.java

# this checks only sources matched by Foo*.java
mvn checkstyle:checkstyle -Dcheckstyle.includes=**\/Foo*.java

# this checks only sources matched by Foo*.java and the source Bar.java
mvn checkstyle:checkstyle -Dcheckstyle.includes=**\/Foo*.java,**\/Bar.java
```

In all cases the result will be

```
# for your further automatic processing
target/checkstyle-result.xml

# for humans to read
target/site/checkstyle.html
```

cheers

Comment: You do not live up to your name. This was a very optimal answer in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the solution proposed by SubOptimal can be combined with the [Suppression Filter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/suppressions-filter.html): it allows to use regular expressions for the names of the files to be excluded from check and even to specify some line ranges.

Comment: unfortunately suppression filter only does suppression, whitelisting is not there