# How to run Maven Checkstyle plugin on modified files only

Tags: java, git, maven, githooks, checkstyle

I am running Maven Checkstyle plugin through pre-commit githook written in python (I think that the same question applies to running it directly from terminal).

The command is:

```
mvn checkstyle:checkstyle
```

However, I would like to run Maven Checkstyle only on files modified by git. For instance, I could run it once for each file. If I want to run it on a specific file, I may define the following pattern (I am not sure why do I need the pattern of stars and dashes in front):

```
mvn checkstyle:checkstyle -Dcheckstyle.includes=**\/*File.java
```

However, I am not able to pass **file path and file name**, for instance:

```
mvn checkstyle:checkstyle -Dcheckstyle.includes=src/main/java/File.java
```

Or, following the above mentioned pattern:

```
mvn checkstyle:checkstyle -Dcheckstyle.includes=**\/*src/main/java/File.java
```

I have tried many other combinations as well, but nothing works. I found this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCHECKSTYLE-394) which is about the same thing, so I am wondering if someone has found a solution to this.

I have also read:

[How to run maven checkstyle plugin on incremental code only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453774/how-to-run-maven-checkstyle-plugin-on-incremental-code-only)

[Is there a maven-git-checkstyle plugin that runs checkstyle goal on git staged files alone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016710/is-there-a-maven-git-checkstyle-plugin-that-runs-checkstyle-goal-on-git-staged-f)

[How to check style arbitrary list of java files from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208568/how-to-check-style-arbitrary-list-of-java-files-from-command-line)

but they do not solve my problem.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example here: [github project of maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://github.com/apache/maven-checkstyle-plugin/blob/27b9ef3efea7a1d168034a3c2e48c0a387e8b894/src/test/plugin-configs/multi-plugin-config.xml#L31)

Put a placeholder in pom and pass the parameter by maven command line.

```
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>${checkstyle.includes}</includes>
    </configuration>
```

Command line: mvn checkstyle:check "-Dcheckstyle.includes=**/File.java"

Comment: Hi quan.s, thank you for your answer. I am not using Java and checkstyle right now so I cannot check if it works for me, but hopefully someone might find your answer useful.

Comment: This would require invoking maven on every changed file?  Or is there a way to pass a list to checkstyle.includes ?  looks like an antpath matcher?

Comment: turns out it's takes a list of CSV values.  The values must be relative to the source path.
ie.. `com/foo/Bar.java` not `src/main/java/com/foo/Bar.java`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using some Node JS tools. Here is what I have:

### Node JS Packaged

`package.json` file:

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "pre-commit": "./scripts/pre-commit-run"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3"
  }
}
```

### Lint Staged Config

`lint-staged.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    '**/*.java': (javaFiles) => {
        const linters = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < javaFiles.length; i++) {
            const filePath = javaFiles[i];
            const fileName = path.parse(filePath).base;
            linters.push(`npm run pre-commit -- ${fileName}`);
        }
        return linters;
    }
}
```

#### Pre-Commit Script

> I couldn't make it work with lint-staged only. If you find a way, please share ;)

`pre-commit-run` file:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
mvn checkstyle:check -Dcheckstyle.includes="**\\/$1"
```

#### Pre-Commit Git Hook

`.husky/pre-commit` file:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"
echo "Running pre-commit hook"
npx lint-staged
```

#### Checkstyle Maven Plugin

`pom.xml` file (the part that matters):

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                            <version>10.7.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${checkstyle-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <!-- Properties for "mvn checkstyle:check" to execute as part of maven build
                     They are conflicting with properties of checkstyle:checkstyle
                     so only one set should be used
                -->
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Specifying configuration here will take effect
                 on the execution of "mvn site",
                 but will NOT take effect on the execution of "mvn checkstyle:check"
                 or "mvn checkstyle:checkstyle"
             -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${checkstyle-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```